# Error in creating background using bootstrap.css

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Am using bootstrap.css file when i write code in side container code it will create white background at output page but when i run i don't get the white background

- instead all output display out the box

full code

[image]
in that picture u could see the white box does't cover the entire content

- i have done everything i cant find whats wrong
- but i could get white box in other page

Comment: full working code  http://jsfiddle.net/sanoj908572/bsfa8qb4/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All your content is floating to left, in order to have a white background that float must be cleared. So you can add an empty `.clearfix` div after just before your `#accordian` container ends, like this

```
<div id="accordian">
    .... your content here...

    <div class="clearfix"></div>
</div>
```

Here's an updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bsfa8qb4/2/)

Answer (score 0):

use `display: inline-block;` in box css class:

```
.box {
padding: 50px 30px;
background: #fff;
position: relative;
border-radius: 10px;
display: inline-block;
}
```